# Is it posiible collapse and expand ExpandableListView inside getGroupView of its adapter?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to set on click listener for container layout on group item of `ExpandableListView`  but when layout clicked it cant collapse and extends like before.

how can i override that method with my customized click listener?

Answer (score 1):

If your getGroupView like this:

```
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean b, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup)
```

then try your onClick like this:

```
    layoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ExpandableListView tmpView = (ExpandableListView)viewGroup;
            if(b) tmpView.collapseGroup(groupPosition); else tmpView.expandGroup(groupPosition);

            // Do something.
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps!